# Half-Edge Data Structure with holes

Tags: loops, data-structures, graphics, edge-detection, boundary

I am trying to implement next/prev of edges in half-edge data structure. But I ran into this question. If there are two holes with a common vertex, will the closed loop of the edges run as in the first picture? Or will it be two separate cycles, as in the second picture?

[image]

In 3ds Max, when the border tool is used, it selects the edge loop as in the first image. Please help me to understand this.

Comment: Do you really have to handle these pathological cases ?